# LOST on WSGIPythonPath takes one argument, Python module search path

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm sorry if ask very dumb question.

But I had no idea what i'm doing, I'm just following the tutorial

Link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6-yJpPEpoE

Now I'm just trying to start up Apache server to run my Django code in productions

I encounter this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:/Frontier_Website/Apache24/bin/httpd.exe -k startserver
AH00526: Syntax error on line 542 of C:/Frontier_Website/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
WSGIPythonPath takes one argument, Python module search path.
```

I'm assuming the error is unable to find my python path, something related to python, which apologies I'm not sure what is looking for.

This are the codes in httpd setting:

```
#python and mod_wsgi setting 
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/user/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\Frontier_Website\FrounterWeb postgreDB-the secnond\FrounterWeb\wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonHome C:/users/user/appdata/local/programs/python/python37
WSGIPythonPath C:\Frontier_Website\FrounterWeb postgreDB-the secnond\zigview

<Directory C:\Frontier_Website\FrounterWeb postgreDB-the secnond\zigview\static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory C:\Frontier_Website\FrounterWeb postgreDB-the secnond\zigview>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

In advance thank you, so much on the help

Answer (score 1):

Use this template to a django app in Apache:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .

    Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject python-home=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

WSGIPythonPath is for additional directories to search for Python modules, not neccesssary if you use a virtual env, I guess

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04 (The apache conf works in Windows too)

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: I active the virtual env and run this in cmd; Apache24\bin\httpd.ex -k start